# Cannot wipe data/factory reset and also cannot restore backup

Tags: custom-roms, external-sd, sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery, cache

I recently flashed a new ROM on my Micromax Canvas 2.2 A114.

The problem was the SD card was detected as phone storage and vice versa. Also, SuperSu binary was not detecting.

So, I go to CWM to flash my stock ROM back again. But now there are numerous errors.

When I try to Wipe Cache, it shows 4 errors of the type
**Can't recover /cache/recovery/lastlog**

If I try to wipe data/factory_reset, it shows error of the type
**format_volume: make_extf4fs failed in /dev/block/mmcblk0p03**

I forgot to take a nandroid backup. What should I do? I'm really worried.

P.S : All I can do now is enter CWM. That's it. No ROM nothing is present in my phone. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Since yesterday I just went into same situation like you had described but then finally able to solve it using so many solutions video watched on Youtube, gone through number of articles and finally solve through [XDA-Developers - Ultimate Kitket ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2779573) site.

You can choose any of ROM for your device, I had chosen Ultimate Kitkat.

1. Also download `Recovery file` for `A114 Canvas 2.2` from [Broodle](http://dl.thebroodle.com/A114_cwm_recovery.img).
2. If you have external SD Card then copy this `recovery.img` file into root of your SD Card. Also place that downloaded file from XDA-Developers site into root folder and the follow `fastboot` from [ADB drivers](http://dl-1.va.us.xda-developers.com/2/6/5/8/4/9/8/MTK-USB-Driver_v1.0948.0.rar?key=-msE7iW_S1Sh0gw0_o-rSA&ts=1439729251) by connecting your mobile device to PC.
3. Once you have downloaded Ultimate Kitket ROM, .rar or .zip file, then copy it to your SD Card's root directory.
4. Now in your computer go to the ADB driver's directory (open `command prompt` as `Run as Administrator` and go to ADB drivers directory).
5. Run following command from command prompt

> fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

It will install CWD recovery.img file to Android device and now your task will become much more easier.

6. Again go for wipe/factory reset option.
7. Now go for `check updates from sd card` and then select your .rar or .zip file, it will ask you for confirmation and say `Yes...` and it will start installation process.
8. After installation it will again give you prompt to `restart`, so restart it.
9. Now you will see a new logo for `Canvas Blade` and your system is up friend.

So through above steps you can restart you dead mobile.